# How to distribute build .apk file of react-native application to different android device?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have made practice application of react-native in android, I had build it and test on my real device which I had connected to my development pc. But when I copy the build .apk file from project folder and distribute among different devices with bluetooth or usb , I can install it on different devices but it shows problem of host address. Does it need development pc ip address always for running the application or can I bind some specific ip and run in all the devices? Please someone suggest me to deploy the general .apk file of my application. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Need more clarification, what is on the development pc?  what *problem of host address*?

Comment: my .apk file doesnot run on different android devices, it only runs on the specific device which i have connected and tested to the pc where i developed the application . when i copy .apk file and install and run on another mobile it will get installed but doesnot run. thats my problem

Comment: You have, read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi) ? Reading that, it sounds very much like a one-to-one setup only.

Comment: yes, i had read this and implemented it. My question is what should we do to our app when it should have to run on more than one devices with various wifi ?

Comment: You can get it to run, enable wifi, access the internal network, and point it to the development pc's ip address, however, it will not be publically/globally accessible, for that, you'd need an external facing pc connected to internet with a public ip address, this would require changing the end point ip to use the public ip address prior to deployment.

Comment: then i should always point to development pc adress?? there is no other possible way to make ip global, so that i can run it in any network.

Comment: use a webhosting package perhaps, or aws?

Comment: do you have suitable informative address about it? please suggest me a link..

Comment: Excuse me, use google, find out, research, learn. SO is not here to do the work for you for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the apk in debug mode, then react-native communicates with your local server in your system. Only when you generate release build then react-native will run without any local server dependency.

So, If you need to distribute apk then you need to create a release apk. This [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) will help you to generate release apk.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that the problem is not with your application, its a network connection problem.

Are your using your System (Desktop) IP address for connection? or please check whether the IP address is a valid IP address.

Along with that also check in your manifest file whether you've added below permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: are you answering  about native android?? i am questioning of react-native .